# Is systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts a valid setting for Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I ran into some issues recently configuring the proxy settings for a Gradle project... specifically with the `systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts`.

Going through the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy) this setting: `systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts = *.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost` is valid, but the [Networking Properties section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) from the Java SDK states that `systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts` does not exist and the non-https sibling will be used instead.

Bottom line: `systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts` didn't work for me. As soon as I deleted that line the script worked (I tested several times toggling it on/off).

So can anyone confirm if that's outdated on the Gradle documentation, or if Gradle does indeed uses it and maps them internally, but the version I was using (Gradle `6.1.1`) had a bug in that regard? Is there a task (or something similar by default) to test/visualize if Gradle is indeed connecting via HTTP or HTTPS so I can corroborate that's working as intended?

Answer (score 2):

It's really hard to tell in retrospect what the issue was in your case.

> but the [Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) section from the Java SDK states that `systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts` does not exist and the non-https sibling will be used instead.

First and foremost, this is true. For reference, the [DefaultProxySelector](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java#L187) in JDK 8 reads

```java
static class NonProxyInfo {
    static final String defStringVal = "localhost|127.*|[::1]|0.0.0.0|[::0]";

    static NonProxyInfo httpNonProxyInfo = new NonProxyInfo("http.nonProxyHosts", null, null, defStringVal);
}

public java.util.List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
    //....
    } else if ("https".equalsIgnoreCase(protocol)) {
        // HTTPS uses the same property as HTTP, for backward
        // compatibility
        pinfo = NonProxyInfo.httpNonProxyInfo;
    }
    //....
}
```

> So can anyone confirm if that's outdated on the Gradle documentation, or if Gradle does indeed uses it and maps them internally, but the version I was using (Gradle 6.1.1) had a bug in that regard?

Gradle indeed reads `https.nonProxyHosts` and maps it internally. See [JavaSystemPropertiesSecureHttpProxySettings](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/b189979845c591d8c4a0032527383df0f6d679b2/subprojects/resources-http/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/resource/transport/http/JavaSystemPropertiesSecureHttpProxySettings.java#L21)  for more details. I'm not aware of any bugs. The commit log's last relevant change was from 2014. The property is used for example when resolving dependencies from remote Maven repositories.

> Is there a task (or something similar by default) to test/visualize if Gradle is indeed connecting via HTTP or HTTPS so I can corroborate that's working as intended?

I'm not aware of any task, be it built-in or contributed by 3rd party plugins. You may get more details on what's going on by inspecting `--info` and `--debug` output.